# how to define fixed size boost circular buffer as class member?

Tags: c++, boost

According to the boost's tutorial, to define a fixed size circular buffer we can do:

```
boost::circular_buffer <int> aspBuffer(3);
```

how ever, when I take this as a private **class member**, error occurs:
expected identifier before numeric constant

When does this happen and how should I do it correctly? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to initialize the member in the constructor of your class

```
class example {
  boost::circular_buffer<int> aspBuffer;

  public:
  example() : aspBuffer(3) {}
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I just checked the document, can I also use aspBuffer.set_capacity(3) in the constructor? Do they work the same?

Comment: @SummerFang, you can. But you'd have to do that in the constructor body, and not in the member initializer list.

Answer (score 0):

Or use set_capacity() function if you wish to change  its buffer size later on.